# Characters make the game

Tags: knowledge, video-games

I wanted to tell a friend about a character in one of the best games I ever played. However, this game is pretty old and I neither remember the name of the game nor of the character. But there are some other things I remember:

- The character I'm looking for also had memory problems, but it was nothing compared to the main character of the game. I don't want to spoil the story, therefore I don't look for the main character.
- He really likes to kill people, but he is not a soldier or warrior like the other two characters I'm not looking for. Assassin would be a better description.
- I'm not looking for the small guy with odd pronunciation, I wonder how anyone can understand what he says.
- I'm neither looking for the little girl nor for their big hairy friend.
- I'm also not looking for the female character who managed to get captured twice during the game.
- There is another female character which was chosen as the 10th worst character on a ranking list. The character I'm looking for is quite the opposite, he even won two awards.
- Finally, the old hermit character is another one I'm not looking for.

Help me Puzzling.SE. You're my only hope.

Comment: So many things remind me of Final Fantasy 7, but there are still some facts, that are contradictory to the characters in the game.

Comment: @WaKai No, it's not Final Fantasy. I've added a new hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was thinking

> HK-47 from Star Wars: KOTOR,

•The character I'm looking for also had memory problems, but it was nothing compared to the main character of the game. I don't want to spoil the story, therefore I don't look for the main character.

> - The main character, Darth Revan, had amnesia, which was a major part of the story.

•He really likes to kill people, but he is not a soldier or warrior like the other two characters I'm not looking for. Assassin would be a better description.

> HK-47 is an assassin droid and really doesn't like people, whom he refers to as "meatbags."  The other two soldiers/warriors represent Canderous Ordo and Carth Onasi.

•I'm not looking for the small guy with odd pronunciation, I wonder how anyone can understand what he says.

> This is the droid T3-M4, who speaks only Binary.

•I'm neither looking for the little girl nor for their big hairy friend.

> Mission Vao the Twi'lek and Zaalbar the Wookiee

•I'm also not looking for the female character who managed to get captured twice during the game.

> Bastila Shan, the Jedi who caused the memory loss of Darth Revan

•There is another female character which was chosen as the 10th worst character on a ranking list. The character I'm looking for is quite the opposite, he even won two awards.

> Juhani, the Cathar Dark Jedi

•Finally, the old hermit character is another one I'm not looking for.

> Jedi Master Jolee Bindo

Comment: Nice, I saw this puzzle late. I loved this game, the Mission/Zaalbar clue gave it away big time. Already with the memory thing I though of Revan, at that point I was like:  ^_^

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> HK-47 from KotOR.

Details:

> 1. Main character was amnesiac, HK needed to have his memories restored.
>  2. He is a hunter-killer droid (assassin).
>  3. Small guy with weird pronunctiation would be Vandar Tokare, a member
>  of Yoda's species.
>  4. The little girl would be Mission, and her wookiee friend Zaalbar.
>  5. Bastila is the character captured twice.
>  6. Juhani was the reviled character (deservedly so, bleh).
>  7. The old hermit is Jolee Bindo.